# Casting two variables

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am looking to cast two variables to a date.

I can get the SQL to work for casting one (first code) but when I want to cast two variables I keep getting errors (see two attempts below).

I have searched for cast double and cast two variables but double comes up with the type double and variable has the same issue. What work should I be searching for or what 'join' do I need to cast two variables.

- One cast (working)

  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT datestart, DateEnd, runcompleted FROM [tblweeklyreports] where Cast(datestart as date) between '" & vDateStart & "' and '" & vDateStart & "'"

-Two cast (not working)

```
 sSQL = "SELECT datestart, DateEnd, runcompleted FROM [tblweeklyreports] where Cast(moduledatestart as date, moduledatecomplete as date) between '" & vDateStart & "' and '" & vDateEnd & "'"
```

and

```
 sSQL = "SELECT datestart, DateEnd, runcompleted FROM [tblweeklyreports] where Cast(moduledatestart as date),(moduledatecomplete as date) between '" & vDateStart & "' and '" & vDateEnd & "'"
```

It must of come up before (a link is all I need, but I can not seem to search for the right wording!)

------------------- Amended version as per discussion --------------

```
Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        Dim vRunCompleted As String = ""
        Dim vDateStartExist As String = ""
        cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("mySQLConnectionString").ConnectionString
        cmd.Connection = cn
        'Open the connection to the database
        cn.Open()
```

Dim vDateStartDate As Date = vDateStart
        Dim vDateEndDate As Date = vDateEnd

```
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [tblresults] where moduledatestart between @from and @to"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", vDateStart)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", vDateEnd)

        Dim str As New StringBuilder
        Dim vdrOkay As String
        str.Append(Chr(34) & " Employee Id" & Chr(34) & "," & "Forename" & "," & Chr(34) & "Surname" & Chr(34) & "," & "Control 1" & "," & Chr(34) & "Control 2" & Chr(34) & "," & "Full code" & "," & "Class Name" & "," & "Year" & ",")
        str.Append(Chr(34) & " Number" & Chr(34) & "," & "Class Start Date" & "," & Chr(34) & "Class End Date" & Chr(34) & "," & "Course Type" & "," & Chr(34) & "Provider Type" & Chr(34) & "," & "Provider" & "," & "Venue" & "," & "Evaluation" & "," & "Duration Hrs" & ",")
        str.Replace(",", vbNewLine, str.Length - 1, 1) ' go to next line

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If (dr.HasRows = True) Then

            Label1.Text = "running"

            While (dr.Read())

                vdrOkay = Trim(StrConv(dr("EmployeeID"), VbStrConv.Uppercase))
                str.Append("=" & Chr(34) & vdrOkay & Chr(34) & ",")

 End While

            Dim vFileName As String = Replace(vDateStart, "/", "_") & "_" & Replace(vDateEnd, "/", "_")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(("C:\sites\Examples\WeeklyReport\" & "ELearning_Report_" & vFileName & ".csv"), str.ToString, False)

        Else
 Label1.Text = "did not run"
        End If
```

Comment: you should use parameritizied queries.

Comment: Edited to show at the bottom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would be no need to cast anything if you went the recommended way of using **parameterized queries**, which also has the nice additional effect of avoiding SQL injection.

In your case this might look like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT datestart, DateEnd, runcompleted FROM [tblweeklyreports] where datestart between @from and @to"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", vDateStart)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", vDateEnd)
```

The problem lies in the way you construct your `WHERE` clause. You can not compare two fields in one go as you're trying. You need to write something like this:

```
SELECT 
    datestart, 
    DateEnd, 
    runcompleted 
FROM [tblweeklyreports] 
where 
    moduledatestart between @from and @to and
    moduledatecomplete between @from and @to
```

Then use SQL parameters  as above.

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is a SQL misunderstand, where he is trying to compare two columns to a single condition, separating the columns with commas.

Comment: Ah, I see. Going to fix my answer

Comment: Also: `.AddWithValue()` is bad. Don't use it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn And why's that?

Comment: The above looks good and I have added this to the bottom of the initial question. The code runs but goes to the "did not run" despite saying 'true' on  line: If (dr.HasRows = True) Then. Excuse the quetion but do I not still need to convert my string to a date? It looks like it is working when I added the conversation. (see original question)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar It forces .Net to infer the type of the parameter, and there are several cases where .Net will get it wrong, sometimes with significant consequences. The query will usually still work, but it can cause per-row data conversions in a query, making things much slower, or it can cause you to miss an index, making things **really** slow. Much better to use the `.Add()` method that explicitly sets the parameter types.

Comment: @indofraiser If `vDateStart` and `vDateEnd` are strings, you need to convert them to `DateTime`. Then, if `moduledatestart` and `moduledatecomplete` are strings, you need to convert them, too.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn You are right about that, it would be better to use the overload where you can explicitly specify the type. However, I don't see how I could miss an index?

Comment: There are a few ways, but one example is if you have a varchar database field. If you just assign a string to a parameter using AddWithValue(), .Net will tend to give it an nvarchar type, and often this is enough to trick sql server out of using good indexes.